# gae long time for calculation mapreduce 500 error python

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, mapreduce, google-app-engine-python

I got a code to work on GAE but am struggling with the 500 error, which looks like due to the long wait (run) time.

I am doing the following:

1. Read the user given info
2. Run some mapreduce method to calculate some stats and send this as email
3. (Re)direct the user to a thank you page, since the results will be emailed

The code works fine on App engine SDK since there is no time limit. However, I keep getting the 500 error when I run the code on GAE. If I do not perform calculations in step 2 then the code works again (redirects to a new page and sends email). I tried doing step 2 after step 3, but keep getting the same error.

Is there any easy way to fix this? I am thinking of something like get the user info and let them know the results will be emailed to them or redirect them to the main page. In the meantime (or after the above) I can run mapreduce in the backend and email the completed results so the time limit does not abort my code.

```
class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        #get info provided in form by user (code not shown here)

        # send them to new page or main page
        self.response.write('<html><body>You wrote:<pre>')
        self.response.write("thanks")
        self.response.write('</pre></body></html>')
        #self.redirect('/')

        dump_content = 'Error'
        try:
            dump_content = long_time_taking_mapreduce_method(user_given_info)    
        except DeadlineExceededError:
            logging.warning("Deadline error")

        send_results_as_email(OUTPFILE, dump_content)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/sign', Guestbook),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: you basically answered the question yourself already. Have a look at the task queue (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) which gives you 10 minutes deadline, instead of 60 seconds in the front end. If 10 minutes is not enough you can request how much time you still have, save the context when you're getting close to the deadline and restart the task from where you left off.

Comment: Thank for the info, but I am little confused. Do you mean run the mapreduce method in taskqueue  or just add the redirection to the taksqueue? Could you put some small code above so I get a better idea. The taskqueue doc makes it seem that I can only run urls in it.

Comment: put the `long_time_taking_mapreduce_method(user_given_info)` call in another RequestHandler. Since that request handler will have a url you can queue that url in the task queue.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of mapreduce is that it runs offline, taking as many tasks and as long as necessary. It's defeating the whole purpose to try and run it within your handler function.

Instead, your mapreduce task itself should call the `send_results_as_email` method once it has a result.

Comment: Any suggestions of how I can call the mapreduce outside the handler function (which gets user params) is much appreciated. For now we can ignore the send email since that is being called at the end by mapreduce method. Thanks.

Comment: The reason I had tried that in the first place was as per the tutorial http://sookocheff.com/post/appengine/mapreduce/programmatic-mapreduce/